# SP2010: IE11 Issue on Rich Text Editor on Edit page

Tags: 2010, javascript, internet-explorer, rte

On the rich text editor field (on page creation or editing), we encounter some issues using IE Edge:

1. Picture positioning is not working properly. The sp.ui.rte.js throws an error that 'style' is undefined. When you refresh the page, it will work properly.
2. Pasting functionality does not work properly. It throws a notfound error (still coming from sp.ui.rte.js)
3. Selecting a text in the rich text editor field automatically duplicates the words before it (without doing any ctrl+c or ctrl+v, really weird). For example:

Sentence: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

I select (in bold): The quick brown fox jumps **over the lazy dog**.

Outcome (without doing anything): The quick brown fox jumps *fox jumps* over the lazy dog.

I was able to replicate this behavior on our other SharePoint sites when I changed the IE version to Edge.

Note: These issues does not happen on IE10 below. Changing the masterpage's compatibility is not allowed unfortunately. They want it on IE11.

This fix has already been implemented in the past:
RTE.Canvas.$1P = function (b) { if (b == undefined) return;

I already tried searching for the root cause, still no luck. I appreciate if you can guys give me an idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!